# Lego rough terrain 42082, page 57 book 1 - how does it connect internally

Tags: technic, building, instructions

Is the dole meant to connect to another cog inside so all the gears rotate the big round cog on top

(Image from [brickinstructions.com](https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/42082/Rough_Terrain_Crane))

[image: page 57, set 42082]

Answer (score 4):

That [Technic, Axle 5L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32073#T=C&C=86) (you called it "dole") is supposed to slot into the [Technic, Axle Connector 2L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538c#T=C&C=86) that was added in step 67 :
[image]